# SmartPTR implementation heap->isValid assertion

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to implement a very simple SmartPointer for learnign purpose, however I'm struggling with an error I can't seem to debug. Even in debug mode I get no clear information what i wrong, only a runtime assertion.

Here's the code for the SmartPTR so far:

```
template <typename TYPE>
class SmartPointer
{
    TYPE* pData;
public:
    SmartPointer(void)
        : pData(0)
    {
        std::cout << "DEFAULT CTOR" << std::endl;
    }

    SmartPointer(TYPE* data)
        : pData(data)
    {
        std::cout << "CTOR WITH TYPE*" << std::endl;
    }

    SmartPointer(const SmartPointer<TYPE>& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "COPY CTOR" << std::endl;
    }

    ~SmartPointer(void)
    { delete pData; }

    SmartPointer<TYPE>& operator=(const SmartPointer<TYPE>& rhs)
    {
        pData = rhs.pData;

        return *this;
    }

    TYPE* operator->(void)
    { return pData; }

    TYPE& operator*(void)
    { return *pData; }
};
```

The class I'm using with this is farily forward. It's a simple Person class that can be found anywhere on the internet, with contructor, copy constructor and overloaded assignment operator. Now with the simple cases I have no problem.

```
SmartPointer<Person> p(new Person("Henry", 42));
p->Display(std::cout, *p); // Prints: Henry - 42
SmartPointer<Person> q(p); // Causes runtime error.
SmartPointer<Person> q;
q = p;                     // The same runtime error as with copy constructor.
```

Any idea where did this go wrong? If it helps here's the Person class:

```
class Person
{
    std::string name;
    unsigned age;
public:
    Person(const char* name, unsigned age)
        : name(name), age(age)
    { std::cout << "PERSON CTOR CALLED!" << std::endl; }
    Person(const Person& rhs)
        : name(rhs.name), age(rhs.age)
    { std::cout << "PERSON COPY CTOR CALLED!" << std::endl; }
    ~Person(void)
    { }
public:
    Person& operator=(const Person& rhs)
    {
        std::cout << "PERSON ASSIGNMENT OPERATOR CALLED!" << std::endl;

        name = std::string(rhs.name);
        age  = rhs.age;

        return *this;
    }
public:
    static std::ostream& Display(std::ostream& os, const Person& p);
};

std::ostream& Person::Display(std::ostream& os, const Person& p)
{
    return os << p.name << " - " << p.age << std::endl;
}
```

Thanks for every help!
 - Joe.

Comment: Is there any error message you get at runtime?

Comment: Well, you get double deletes because your smart pointer doesn't do anything smart.

Comment: Well with Debug it gives Unhandled exception at 0x6A7B4F98 in SharedPointer_CPP.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFEEEFEE2.

in dbgdel.cpp

/* verify block type */
_ASSERTE(_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse));

Comment: No offense but that's the dumbest smart pointer I've ever seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your smart pointer simply copies the underlying pointer in the <strike>copy constructor and</strike> assignment operator. It also deletes the pointer in the destructor. So each time you copy or you assign one of these smart pointers, you get more than one object holding a pointer to something they will all attempt to delete.

Concerning the copy constructor (thanks to @andyprowl for pointing this out), the smart pointer class holds an uninitialized pointer, which it tries to call `delete` on in the destructor. This is undefined behaviour.

There is no general solution to this problem: you have to specify how you want the smart pointer to behave, and what kind of ownership, if any, it implements.

Comment: Ah Also recognised that I failed to copy the correct copy constructor...
SmartPointer(const SmartPointer<TYPE>& rhs)
  : pData(rhs.pData)
 { }

On the other hand. I know the drawbacks of SmartPointers, but its not the issue here. Deletion of a nullPointer shouldn't fail. So when q goes out of scope it will call SmartPtr::~SmartPTR(void) { delete pData; pData = 0; }
The problem here is: Whenever I create a copy of an existing SmartPTR it fails. It fails before the destructors are actually called. No destructor is executed but the code fails.

Comment: Joey, I think you have some learning to do on C++. In particular what it means to copy an object. Just setting pData = 0; is not going to help because **the other object**, the one that hasn't been destructed yet, still has a non-NULL pData which is pointing at deleted memory.

Comment: @Joey OK, with your *real* copy constructor, you get the same problem as with your assignment operator, i.e. the double delete. Setting the `pData` of each object to `0` in the constructor doesn't change anything.